# What is a symbol in programmation as referred in ar command

Tags: c, static, symbols, libraries

I see this term a lot, 'symbol', and after searching on google I still can't find a definition that makes sense to me.

For example in the manual of `ar` command on Linux, it's said :

> ar creates an index to the symbols defined in relocatable object modules in the archive when you specify the modifier s.

Are function declarations / variable declarations / defines / structure declarations etc, symbols ? Or is a symbol a term for .o files ?

In this context, what is a symbol exactly ? Act like I'm a complete beginner who knows nothing when you form your answer please !

Comment: It's names of things.  Functions, structs, global or static variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)#:~:text=A%20symbol%20in%20computer%20programming,them%20in%20a%20symbol%20table. Found with a Google search for *symbol (programming)*.

Comment: My pleasure.  I wrote up an answer with more detail.  Make sure you accept whatever answered your question best (by clicking the check mark) so we know you are all set.

Comment: @KenWhite I read it before making this post, however as I said that definition didn't make sense to me. That's why in this thread I asked "Act like I'm a complete beginner who knows nothing when you form your answer please" so that I would receive a definition with terms that I'm more likely to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symbol is the name of [things](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) (functions, variables etc).  Here is an example file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
    char *a;
};
struct foo global_foo;
static struct foo static_foo;

struct foo *foo_create() {
     return malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
}
```

which I then compile and make an archive and then use nm to list its symbols:

```
$ gcc -c 1.c && ar -rc 1.a 1.o && nm -s 1.a

Archive index:
global_foo in 1.o
foo_create in 1.o

1.o:
0000000000000000 T foo_create
0000000000000000 B global_foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U malloc
0000000000000008 b static_foo
```

Comment: That makes it perfectly clear, thanks once again for your time explaining it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to define symbol. If you define symbol as "something that stands for or suggests something else by reason of relationship, association, convention, or accidental resemblance" ([definition from Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/symbol)), then yes, you can say that variable names, function names, struct names, etc. are symbols because they *symbolize* variables, functions, struct, etc.

If you define [symbol as a data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)), then that is something a little different. A symbol in this case would be something you create that you can guarantee it to be unique. This is very useful for cases where you want to store a bunch of names, but you want to make sure that no names conflict with each other by making them unique.

The particular example that you gave us about the `ar` command is talking about symbols as a data type. The `ar` command stores references to archived files that are internally mapped in a data structure called a symbol table, which essentially means that `ar` guarantees that each and every names of file that are archived are unique (the way they do this is by mapping the names of each file to an index, so even if they were files with the same name, it would be unique to a specific number that it is mapped to).

Comment: I marked Allan's answer as accepted answered, because it gives me an answer more newbie friendly which is what I asked. However your answer adds a little more depth and both your answers mixed are a really good Accepted answer. So, many thanks to you too.

Comment: @lyeaf No problem! I am glad to have been helpful. This is totally optional, but it would help me a lot if you would be willing to upvote my answer if you thought it was helpful (even if you liked the other answer better).

Comment: I tried, but it says : "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."
I suppose when I'll have 15 reputations, all the feedback I've sent in the past will become public